# Data validator VBA excel- compare a value within a string in one cell to a value in another

Tags: date, excel, vba

Have not been able to find anything that fits my needs.

I have two columns of values (L and U). Column L contains a file names that includes a date in MM-DD-YYYY format (example yadayadayada thru (03-15-2015).pdf) column U contains a date. What I need to do is have a macro compare the date within the file name to the date in the column U. Other dates may appear within the text in column L but the date I need to compare against is always after "thru" and in parentheses followed by the file extension.  If they do not match, I need the value in column U highlighted and replaced with the text "FAIL". I'm going to continue searching but any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it have to be VBA? This can be accomplished with Conditional Formatting.
Apply this conditional format formula to column U:

```
=AND(U1<>"",L1<>"",U1<>--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(L1," ",REPT(" ",255)),255)),")",REPT(" ",255)),2,255)))
```

And set the number format to Custom `"FAIL"` with yellow (or the highlight color of your choice) fill.

**EDIT**

If it has to be VBA, then this should work for you:

```
Sub tgr()

    Const HeaderRow As Long = 1 'Change to your actual header row

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngFail As Range
    Dim rngFiles As Range
    Dim FileCell As Range
    Dim dDate As Double

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Set rngFiles = ws.Range("L" & HeaderRow + 1, ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp))
    If rngFiles.Row < HeaderRow + 1 Then Exit Sub 'No data

    For Each FileCell In rngFiles.Cells
        If Len(Trim(FileCell.Text)) > 0 Then
            dDate = 0
            On Error Resume Next
            dDate = CDbl(CDate(Trim(Mid(Replace(Trim(Right(Replace(FileCell.Text, " ", String(255, " ")), 255)), ")", String(255, " ")), 2, 255))))
            On Error GoTo 0
            If dDate <> ws.Cells(FileCell.Row, "U").Value2 Then
                Select Case (rngFail Is Nothing)
                    Case True:  Set rngFail = ws.Cells(FileCell.Row, "U")
                    Case Else:  Set rngFail = Union(rngFail, ws.Cells(FileCell.Row, "U"))
                End Select
            End If
        End If
    Next FileCell

    If Not rngFail Is Nothing Then
        rngFail.Value = "FAIL"
        rngFail.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This does technically do what I want it to, however it doesn't actually replace the values stored in column U, just reformats it.  If the actual value isn't changed, this worksheet could still upload incorrect data.  If the text changes from something other than a date, then it will fail to upload.

Comment: Are there ever blank cells in either column U or L?

Comment: Yes, but if there is a value in L there must be a value in U.